# Division by t of an Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

My problem is to find a function $g(s)$, solution of the equation:
$$ \frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ f(s)\right\}(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ g(s)\}(t)$$

I know the general property:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ g(s) \}(t)=\frac{(-1)^n}{t^n} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{d^ng(s)}{ds^n}\right\}(t)$$
from which, for $n=1$ we get:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ g(s) \}(t)=-\frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{g'(s)\}(t)$$
So, if I take, for example:
$$g(s)=\int f(s) ds$$
from the previous property I get:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ g(s)\}(t)=-\frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ g'(s)\}(t)=-\frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ f(s)\}(t)$$
so:
$$\frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ f(s)\}(t)=-\mathcal{L}^{-1} \{ g(s)\}(t)= \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{- \int f(s)ds\right\}(t)$$
My problem is that the function $g(s)$ is not uniquely determined because indefinite integral is defined up to a constant; for all type of functions in the form, for example:
$$g_1(s)=g(s)+C, \; C \; \text{constant}$$
the result is the same.

The are known results or conditions on $f$ to uniquely determine $g(s)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Since $g$ is Laplace transform of some function $g(s) \to 0$ as $s \to \infty $. This determines the value of the constant.

Comment: A necessary condition for a function to admit Inverse Laplace Transform is to be of exponential type. Your limit is due to this condition?